# Getting SubMatches from RegEx return from Email to populate cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I need to download data (currency rates) from a selected email in outlook and load them into specific cells in excel. Marko is run from excel. I'm using a function ***regexp*** to retrieve the data.
I have defined 2 types of patterns with which I search for data, the macro finds them but does not assign them to cells.  The way I tried to assign the found data is: ***matches.Item(0).SubMatches***.

```
Sub data_from_email()

Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim KSell, KBuy, KAvr As String 'value of currency rates)
Dim sText As String
Dim Reg1, Reg2 As Object
Dim M1 As Object
Dim m As Object

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set xlSheet = wb.Sheets("name")
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application


sText = olItem.Body 'assignment of email content

'pattern of value searched variant 1 (currency rates with a dot as a separator)
Set Reg1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With Reg1
    .Pattern = "[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With
If Reg1.Test(sText) Then
        Set m1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each m In m1
        KSell = m.SubMatches(2) 
        KBuy = m.SubMatches(1) 
        KAvr = m.SubMatches(0)
        Next
    End If

'pattern of value searched variant 2 (currency rates with a comma as a separator)
Set Reg2 = New RegExp
With Reg2
    .Pattern = "[0-9]\,[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With
If Reg1.Test(sText) Then
        Set m1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each m In m1
        KSell = m.SubMatches(2) 
        KBuy = m.SubMatches(1)
        KAvr = m.SubMatches(0) 
        Next
    End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by trial and error. Turns out that removing ***Submatches*** worked. This code worked:

```
Sub data_from_email()

    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim KSell, KBuy, KAvr As String 'value of currency rates)
    Dim sText As String
    Dim Reg1, Reg2 As Object
    Dim M1 As Object

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set xlSheet = wb.Sheets("name")
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application


    sText = olItem.Body 'assignment of email content
    
    'pattern of value searched variant 1 (currency rates with a dot as a separator)
    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    If Reg1.Test(sText) Then
        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)

    End If
    
    'pattern of value searched variant 2 (currency rates with a comma as a separator)
    Set Reg2 = New RegExp
    With Reg2
        .Pattern = "[0-9]\,[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    If Reg2.Test(sText) Then
        Set M1 = Reg2.Execute(sText)

    End If
 
    'assigning data to a cell
           
        KSell = M1(2).Value
        KBuy = M1(1).Value 'second found text matching the pattern
        KAvr = M1(0).Value 'first found text matching the pattern

        
    With xlSheet
        .Range("E3") = Replace(KSell, ".", ",") 'assigment value of currency rates to cells and change a dot to a comma)
        .Range("D3") = Replace(KBuy, ".", ",")
        .Range("C3") = Replace(KAvr, ".", ",")
    End With
 
        End Sub
```

Comment: The reason it worked is that the regex returns a 1D array.  There is no `Submatches` in vba arrays.